# Is it possible to hide the express cookie from chrome console?

Tags: javascript, express, cookies

I am using the following express code, to perform the user authentication.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const accessTokenSecret = 'my secret';

function loginAPI(req,res){
  const { loginName, adminPwd } = req.body;
  if ((loginName==='admin') && (adminPwd==='password')){
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({ username: loginName }, accessTokenSecret,{ expiresIn: '1h' });
    res.cookie('isAdmin',accessToken,{
      path:'/privateAPI/',
      httpOnly:true,
      signed: true, 
      maxAge:3600000
    });
    
    res.json({
      accessToken
    }).send();
    
  } else {
    res.status(401).send();
  }  
};
```

After I authenticated the application using Chrome, I found that my cookies can be found in the chrome console.

After that, I use Firefox to browse the protected URL, the application can redirect me to the login form.

Unfortunately, after I copied the cookie from chrome console to firebox console,  then I press "F5" button,

I can browse the protected URL without login successfully.

So, I want to know is there any to hide the cookie from the Chrome console?

Comment: That is how cookies work........ answer is no, you can not hide them

Comment: _“I can browse the protected URL without login successfully.”_ - and what exactly would be the problem with that to begin with, in the given scenario? The user has successfully logged in via Chrome, otherwise they would not have that cookie in the first place. So where exactly is any harm done now, by them switching to a different browser? They could simply enter the actual login credentials they have, in Firefox again - the result would be pretty much the same, no?

Comment: No, the browser has to store the cookie somewhere.  Unless other people have access to this machine, there is no security issues either.  If security is an issue, due to multiple users accessing machine, I personally wouldn't use cookie's, but a token authentication backed with SessionStorage.  SessionStorage has the advantage here, because when the user closes Tab/browser, authentication tokens are then removed.  But even then back dooring the information to Firefox is still totally possible.   The question you need to ask, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: After I found the above phenomenon, I wonder whether it is a security issue, I just want to clarify it.